# Return function after for loop and nested anonymous functions finish executing

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to execute some code AFTER I create a new array inside a function that takes an array of image files as input. This function loops over the files and has two nested anonymous functions inside of it. The main goal is to compress files uploaded by users before saving them to the database.

The compression part works great. The issue is that when I call the `compressFiles` function the function returns too early so the new `result` array is empty. If I add a `setTimeout` of about a second the array holds the newly compressed files just fine.

I know this is probably an async issue but I've read so many questions here on stackoverflow and I still can't wrap my head around it. So what would be the best way to return the `compressFiles` function AFTER the for loop and the anonymous function inside of it are done? Or am I just going about this the wrong way? I have tried nesting promises but have failed to arrive at a solution.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Calling and logging the `compressFiles` function:

```
handleFiles(files) {
  const compressedFiles = this.compressFiles(files)
  console.log(compressedFiles)
} // End handleFiles
```

Here is the `compressFiles` function:

```
compressFiles(files) {
// this function compresses image files
let result = []
  console.log('starting loop')
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
      console.log('file' + i)
      let file = files[i]
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        const imgElement = document.createElement('img')
        imgElement.src = e.target.result

        imgElement.onload = (e) => {
          const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
          const MAX_WIDTH = 150
          
          const scale = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width
          canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH
          canvas.height = e.target.height * scale
          
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
          ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
          
          const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, 'image/jpeg')
          ctx.canvas.toBlob( (blob) => {
            //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below
            var compressedFile = new File([blob], file.name);
            result.push(compressedFile)
            this.compressedFiles.push(compressedFile)
            console.log(i)
          }, e.target, 'image/jpeg')
        }
      }
  } // end for
return result
} // End compressFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a counter and a callback function:

```js
compressFiles(files, callback) {
   // this function compresses image files

   //define total files and counter
   const countTotal = files.length;
   let countLoaded = 0;

   let result = []

   console.log('starting loop')

   for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
      console.log('file' + i)
      let file = files[i]
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)

      reader.onload = (e) => {
         const imgElement = document.createElement('img')
         imgElement.src = e.target.result

         imgElement.onload = (e) => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            const MAX_WIDTH = 150
            
            const scale = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width
            canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH
            canvas.height = e.target.height * scale
            
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            
            const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, 'image/jpeg')
            ctx.canvas.toBlob( (blob) => {
               //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below
               var compressedFile = new File([blob], file.name);
               result.push(compressedFile)
               this.compressedFiles.push(compressedFile)
               console.log(i)

               countLoaded++;

               //each time an image finishes loading, check if all images have now been loaded
               if(countLoaded === countTotal) {
                  //call a function with the result
                  callback(result);
               };
            }, e.target, 'image/jpeg')
         }
      }
   } // end for
} // End compressFiles
```

The above increments `countLoaded` at the end of the `imgElement.onload` function. If the number of images loaded is equal to the number of elements in the `files` array, then you are done and want to return the result. This is achieved using a callback function which returns the results array, because as you say, this is an async situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added your suggestions, however the code is still not quite executing in the right order. I've added a `console.log(countLoaded)` right after `result.push(compressedFile)` and a `console.log(result)` inside the if statement that checks if `countLoaded === countTotal`. This is what the console shows:
`[]
4
4
4
4`

Comment: Logging the parameter in the callback also shows an empty array. Again, the code does append the new files to the result array but AFTER the callback is executed.

Comment: Fixed it! I've moved the `countLoaded++` and if statement above the `}, e.target, 'image/jpeg')` line so that they don't get executed until the end of that nested function. That way the `result` array is filled when calling the callback (`sendFiles`). Thanks again for the help @sbgib.

Comment: You're welcome! Well done! That makes sense - it seems the `ctx.canvas.toBlob()` function was also asynchronous, so the counter and callback needed to be inside there instead. I've updated the answer to reflect this. :)